# Uploading file using axios

Tags: django, api, file, django-rest-framework, axios

Hi I'm trying to upload a file to server and I'm having difficulty sending the file. I'm using Django at the backend and I've already set up a put endpoint allowing users to send files and I confirmed it works as intended using postman. However, I'm having trouble uploading on the frontend. So this is how my code looks on the frontend end.

```
selectFileManually.addEventListener('change', function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
            axios.put('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/fileupload/', {
                file: this.files[0]
            }).then(resp => console.log(resp.data)).catch(err => console.log(err.response.data))
        }
    }
})
```

Here `selectFileManually` is an `input[type='file']`. However, when I send this request the server comes back with the following error: `"Missing filename. Request should include a Content-Disposition header with a filename parameter` and when I look at the payload it's complete empty: `{file: {}}' even though you can clearly see I provided a file to send. This is how my code looks at the backend

```
# views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.views import APIView 
from rest_framework.response import Response 
from rest_framework.parsers import FileUploadParser, MultiPartParser
import os

# Create your views here.

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

class FileUploadView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FileUploadParser, )

    def put(self, request, format=None):
        print(request.data)
        with open(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'api/media', request.data['file'].name), 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in request.data['file'].chunks():
                f.write(chunk)
        return Response(status=204) 




#urls.py 
from django.urls import path 
from . import views 

urlpatterns = [
    path('fileupload/', views.FileUploadView.as_view()),
]
```

Could somebody please help me. I know that this.files[0] is not empty since the console logged the files and it showed me that it was indeed the right content

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#fileuploadparser), you need to specify a filename parameter for the view to handle the request. This can be done in two ways:

**1. The view can be called using the filename URL keyword argument**, then that argument is set as the filename.To achieve this you need to change your url pattern to

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('fileupload/(?P<filename>[^/]+)$', views.FileUploadView.as_view()),
]
```

**2. If the view is called without the filename URL keyword argument, then the client must set it in the *`Content-Disposition`* HTTP header.** It is then handled by FileUploadParser in the views.

For eg `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=image.jpg.`

Either way, you need to access filename while making a request.
In your case, since your url pattern does not contain a filename argument you need to set headers to include *`Content-Disposition`*.

Assuming `this.files[0]` is a fileObject, you can get filename by simply doing `this.files[0].name`. Now setting headers on the axios request, so your front end code should look like this.

```
selectFileManually.addEventListener('change', function(event){    
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
            axios.put('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/fileupload/', {
                file: this.files[0]
            },{headers:{
                         'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=this.files[0].name'
                      }
              },
    ).then(resp => console.log(resp.data)).catch(err => console.log(err.response.data))
        }
    }
})
```

Hope this helps !